# What are `(,)` and `,` in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain the difference between `(,)` and `,` in JavaScript and how these operations are called?

```
var a = 42, b;
b = ( a++, a );

var a = 42, b;
b = a++, a;
```

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch5.md#operator-precedence   - scroll a bit down.

Comment: after google-ing for `comma operator` I've found this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator   (:

Comment: @num8er Thanks. I didn't know how it is called so I haven't found much.

Comment: with `()` it's execution of expressions and returning last expression. without `()` it's just list of expressions: `expr1, expr2, expr3...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is already in your source: [Operator Precedence](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch5.md#operator-precedence)

The following code outputs as:

```
var a = 42, b;
b = ( a++, a );

a;  // 43
b;  // 43
```

But what would happen if we remove the `( )`?

```
var a = 42, b;
b = a++, a;

a;  // 43
b;  // 42
```

> Because the `,` operator has a lower precedence than the `=` operator.
>   So, `b = a++, a` is interpreted as `(b = a++), a`. Because `a++` has after side effects, the assigned value to
>   `b` is the value 42 before the `++` changes `a`.

`()` is used to enforce Order of Operations. [Operator precedence on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Answer (score 2):

`()` just executes code inside before assigning value to **b**.
So `b = ( a++, a );` will do:

1. **a** increment by one
2. **b** equals to **a**

And `,` alone creates a second variable and assigns value to it (undefined at this case). Its just a shorthand:

`var a = 42, b;` is the same as:

```
var a = 42, 
var b;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

```
var x = 1;

x = (x++, x);

console.log(x);
// expected output: 2

x = (2, 3);

console.log(x);
// expected output: 3
```

Comment: copy pasting documentation cannot be called "answer" (: